# Are my disks within this MSA storage failing?

Tags: hp, diagnostic, hp-modular-smart-array

[image: Error]

When I go into my HP Array Configuration Utility, there is no errors and and warnings. No visible amber lights either. Should I swap out the disks? This Windows server lost the storage about 4 times this week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have some prefailure warnings, get them swapped out ASAP.

Comment: The storage just keeps going offline as soon as we put any stress onto it. I'm rebuilding one disk at a time. Will probably take awhile! Thanks.

Comment: I can imagine so, but it needs to be done, good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you search for more information about this error before you start replacing any hdd's.

Info from HP support site about this: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/hard-drive-error-640006-on-ML350G5/td-p/5597711#.UGQfJFEv-J8

If you don't care about the cost of replacing the disks, replace them as soon as you can. You could always do the diagnostics of the disks on a second test server later, just to determine if your disk actually are bad or if it's the HPID Tool that is reporting false positives.